# ReactNative, Embed Code From File with Parameters

Tags: react-native

I want to embed javascript code in a ReactNative Component without creating an entirely new component (a plugin I'm using doesn't allow the component to be used outside of it).

Something like this:

`Home.js`

```
render() {
  <View>
    embed('otherFile.js')
  </View>
}
```

`otherFile.js`

```
<Text>Hello</Text>
```

Note: I know components can do this, but they won't work for this situation.

I need to embed the .js file as if it was manually put into the Home.js file

Is something like that possible in ReactNative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use otherFile.js in home.js like this.

```
import otherFile from '/path upto otherFile/';

render() {
  <View>
    <otherFile/>
  </View>
}
```